# GRC implementation for IQ data acquisition of 2-GFSK Radio

Tags: fsk, equalizer, channel, symbol-timing

I am trying to design a 2-GFSK receiver for acquiring IQ symbols. The aim is to implement the entire receiver chain but the decision stage.

The 2-GFSK waveform is being generated by a standard IoT device. The application is RF Finger Print Identification. There are constraints to intended goal and i am not able to converge to a direction to exhaust my efforts. To the best of my understanding, following challenges are to be addressed:

1. There is no information on the Transmiter Pulse Shaping filter available.
2. There are no training symbols in the preamble.
3. GFSK modulation has non-continuous phase unlike GMSK, the I/Q unit circle keeps rotating.

Based on the constraints, I am limited in my approach.

I am finding it very difficult to estimate the signal start time/sampling point t=KT since I dont know how to realize an equivalent matched filter. Knowing, it is a gaussian shaped filter, i could not devise the Rx filter in GNU Radio companion. I tried the Polyphase clock sync using an arbitrary gaussian filter but to no avail.

My SNR is strong enough and i can visualize the IQ symbols.
Since the IQ symbols are rotating clockwise or anticlockwise depending upon the data symbol being 0 or 1, I want to know if i can ever be able to estimate the correct sampling point.

Besides, i want to compensate for CFO followed by channel equalization. The eventual goal is to cleanse the transmitted IQ as close to its original form at the receiver as possible, except demodulating the IQ symbols as 0 or 1. We just want the signature of transmitted IQ.
Please guide me how to approach this problem.

Comment: Your opening sentence is a bit confusing: Do you care about GFSK reception, or just about the raw IQ samples?

Comment: "There is no information on the Transmiter Pulse Shaping filter available." Um, there's *G* in GFSK!

Comment: "GFSK modulation has non-continuous phase" that seems to be wrong. If that was the case, the data symbols would not have been G-shaped prior to being subject to frequency modulation. It is, however, true, that the phase need not be always the same at any point in the symbol period for any two different symbol sequences.

Comment: *I don't know how to realize an equivalent matched filter.* Nobody does, because that doesn't exist: GFSK (and FSK in general) is not a *linear modulation*, and pulse shaping isn't done on the time-domain signal, so no matched filter exists.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr Müller, let me go through the problem statement again as i comment in reponse to your valuable feedback.
1. I care about the IQ samples which are GFSK modulated, the aim is to devise a receiver that does everything as a normal GFSK receiver would, except I am not interested in demodulating the transmitted symbols to data bits.

2. The G in the GFSK is all the information, as i understand, i was expecting i would be able to use a matched filter in time domain to find the optimum sampling point.

Comment: 3. The phase does not need to be and is always changing even if we sample at the exact time during a symbol period T. This is a problem as my channel equalizer in the absence of pilot symbols must be a blind one, say CMA with a modulus of 1 for a normalized case. I get a pretty rounded circle on my receiver right now.

Comment: Pleaseguide me as i proceed, if i am able to normalize my input IQ symbols and use CMA, will I be able to converge given my symbols always keep rotating?

Comment: 2. No, the G in GFSK is for "Gaussian", and it's Gaussian pulse filtering that's applied to the data pulses *before* going into an integrator and a phase modulator (i.e., into a frequency modulator with continuous phase!)

Comment: 3. A CMA equalizer has the problem that the signal has constant modulus *all the time*, so it's hard to identify which delay led to a specific receive amplitude.

Comment: *given my symbols always keep rotating*, well, they *are* FSK symbols, not PSK. Again, this is *not* a linear modulation!

Comment: 2. Yes the purpose of Gaussian pulse shaping is to improve the spectral efficiency only and not to let the receiver devise an equivalent matched filter, its well understood now. Thankx

Comment: 3. What do i do then? i cannot quit...must find a way forward...:')

Comment: Yes, understood. This non-linearity is not an issue in GMSK as i understand but a problem in GFSK, how does one equalize a GFSK signal then anyway?...:(

Comment: Besides, as per my observation of GMSK, the phase does not change for consecutive symbols, Is the continuous phase property helping with that? Simulation shows linearity in my GNU Radio Companion. The IQ symbols remain intact on the unit circle for a constant input of 0 or 1.

Comment: the unit circle is inherent for **any** FSK, and says nothing about phase change of consecutive symbols; so that's not an indication at all. The question here is how we need to talk about phase, seeing that this is not a single carrier, but two.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, understood. This non-linearity is not an issue in GMSK as i understand but a problem in GFSK, how does one equalize a GFSK signal then anyway?

Not at all, usually. GFSK use cases are systems that are complexity-bounded with relatively flat channels.

However, that won't help you for your device identification. So, you get to do the full chain from ground up:

- Build a proper GFSK CFO recovery (automatic filtering to relevant bandwidth, PLL-based tracking of the carrier, averaging the frequency), then
- a timing recovery (error signal of the PLL *is* a bimodal pulse-shaped signal, so apply your timing recovery to that, to extract absolute timing and symbol rate),
- a decision-aided equalizer, quite possibly by estimating the properties of the Gaussian data pulse filter and the frequency modulator, then use that to re-create a noise-free version of your received signal, and do a channel estimate based on the comparison of that with your raw received signal.

You'd be left with *some* information about your original transmitter.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed response. Although i did not understand some aspects.
1.How to do automatic filtering?...I have MATLAB and GNU Radio available
2.  The only timing recovery I know is the one using matched filtering, for zero ISI matched filter, the point where we get maximum SNR at point T, essentially t=kT. I dont know how to do timing recovery in non-linear modulation techniques.
3. Can I use a transmission line after attenuation and observe the waveform once I have the CFO and timing done.
With knowNn signal attenuation and no channel impairements, only AWGN

Comment: 1. do a spectral analysis of your receive signal, find the occupied bandwidth. This can be as simple as estimating the PSD with an FFT, or through Yule-Walker equations, or through neural networks running on spectrograms, or… this depends on how well you can pre-segment your spectrum to "only" see your signal of interest.

Comment: 2. then resesarch other timing recovery methods! You might end up doing something like a modified Gardner or such.

Comment: 3. I don't understand the question. A transmission line is a physical thing?

Comment: 1. Yes GNU Radio companion shows PSD using FFT. I was able to use a low pass filter to allow only the signal of interest. I will focus on exactly pre-sementing my signal of interest. some value of sidebands might be permissible though?
2. I will study about Gardner. Thank you for the heads up.
3.  Yes i have the transmitter in my lab, i can connect it to my receiver using an RF cable through an attenuator to see the transmitted waveform with no channel impairements. Once, CFO and timing recovery are done, this should give me the closest thing to match at receiver. plz suggest?

Comment: 3. I still don't understand, sorry.

Comment: If i connect the device to be studied through an RF cable with my receiver after attenuating it through an RF attenuator...the transmitted signal never goes into the air and routes to the receiver without channel impairement. Once CFO compensation and timing recovery are done. We should have a signal at the receiver with no channel impairements. We can use this as a reference for training our equalizer and compare the signal received over the channel with this reference later in inference stage.

Comment: that depends – if your signal is so perfectly repeatable,  what exactly are you basing your finger print on? I'd expect that among a billion deployed low-cost GFSK transmitters, most are *pretty* similar, and you need to go for temporal changes to discern them

Comment: No, right now the focus is only to equalize the channel impairements. I am only focused on devising a complete GFSK chain and three stages you highlighted are the ones I have always targetted but I have not been able to understand how to proceed. 
Timing, CFO and Equalization
In a textbook I am reading right now written by Analog Devices, SDR for Engineers. It has Timing recovery chapter before CFO in the sequence.

Comment: SDR4Engineers by Travis and Robin isn't a bad text at all! But it might not be going deep enough into the matter, and it only highlights specific examples of recovery algorithms. For your slightly non-standard problem, you might need to dive a bit into stochastic signal modelling (Kay) and basics of synchronization (Mengali, but that will be hard to get your hands on)

Comment: Yes, SDR4Engineers only focuss on the matched filtered cases. I found kay in my unversity library. But Mengali as you said could not be found. I dont know what to do

Comment: read SDR4Engineers, then see whether you feel you have enough info. If not, do visit the other books.

Comment: Respected Sir Müller, I read synchronization topic in the Digital Communication by Sklar and established my mathematical and intuitive understanding of PLL. Previously, I had no understanding of loop filter, its order and impact of order to lock on the phase depending on the type of phase or frequency offset present in the incoming signal. Am i moving in the right direction? 
So as i understand, we want to convert our GFSK demodulation into a coherent detection problem,our receiver will become a BPSK one. So the IQ symbols are always sampled at the same time, hence the synchronization

Comment: Hey, no need to be this formal :) yes! This sound like you're moving in a very good direction. The problem really lies in, as you say, converting the (G)FSK demodulation problem into one of coherent detection. I don't immediately see a value to that, as the transmitted absolute phase is not carrying any information – you really need to detect the frequency, not the phase, and coherent detection can't help you with that, if the phase of the individual symbols aren't defined at the sample instant (which they aren't! This is still an FSK, not a PSK). You can of course first do a frequency …

Comment: … demodulation on the received signal (for example, using a PLL, or using filter banks, or using tan⁻¹ or…), but what you'd get is a real-valued signal (frequency over time), and real signals always have phase 0, so coherent detection isn't helpful there, either.

Comment: There is a reason to be formal because I saw one of your GNU Radio models yesterday as an example for PLL as i remember. I feet honored to be having this conversation with you. 
Sir, please see the following picture, this is a simulation of GMSK in MATLAB, as you can see, after neccesary remediations, the IQ symbols can be found as we would expect in an OQPSK modulation. So the sampling being done at the right instant is indeed producing the phase at the right time. Why is it not possible in GFSK? Why we cannot have a coherent detection for GFSK?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This picture is a GMSK simulation in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I component of GFSK modulated signal. The byte value is 0x0F. Only a single byte sent per frame.

Comment: Sir Muller, I was able to get this sample using GNU Radio companion. As you can see the early part of the signal is preamble and serves the most usefulness for us. Your feedback in this regard is highly appreciated please.