# Unable to discern between GFSK and BPSK

Tags: bpsk, fsk

[image]
[image]
Greetings Forum!
I posted a question sometime back and got some relevant feedback on that question however I have now run into another issue.
I am using a radio to transmit a 2-GFSK waveform. I used GNU Radio Companion 3.10 to see the signal in time domain in a LoS channel condition. However, I am confused as to what is happening here. Is this BPSK or GFSK? I am not seeing 2 distinct frequencies here and I see the output of quadrature demodulator switching between 0 and 1 whenever the phase changes. I am attaching the GRC file as well as the I component of signal and synchronized output of Quadrature Demodulator.
Please advise
Best Regards

Comment: This is the link to my main problem
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89482/grc-implementation-for-iq-data-acquisition-of-2-gfsk-radio